# Issue with teradata to mysql query conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

***Teradata Query:-***

```
   select  min(elapsed_sec) over (partition by job_name, parent_job_name order by elapsed_sec rows between 1 following and 1 following) - elapsed_sec as diff from xyz
```

***Output of Teradata Query:-***

```
elapsed_sec row_count row_no diff
0.000       207        143  1.000
1.000       207        144  0.000
1.000       207        145  0.000
1.000       207        146  0.000
1.000       207        147  4,555.000
4,556.000   207        148  1,250.000
5,806.000   207        149  2,038.000
7,844.000   207        150  73.000
```

> **Note**:- diff is the difference betweeen current_row and next_row
> eg.
> 1-0=1 in first row, 1-1=0 in 2nd row My mysql5.6 doesn't support this
> feature. Please help to get desired result

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work in the more recent versions of MySQL.  So, my first recommendation is to update to MySQL 8+.

Until you do that, one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select ( (select min(elapsed_sec) 
          from xyz xyz2
          where xyz2.job_name = xyz.job_name and
                xyz2.parent_job_name = xyz.parent_job_name and
                xyz2.elapsed_sec > xyz.elapsed_sec
         ) - elapsed_sec) as diff
from xyz;
```